# Joi to validate alternatives depending on multiple keys

Tags: node.js, validation, schema, joi

Using [Joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi), how do I make the schema require `rent.max` only when `type` is either `A` or `B` AND `subType` is either `AA` or `BB`? Here's my attempt.

```
const Joi = require("joi");
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
  type: Joi.string().valid('A', 'B', 'C').required(),
  subType: Joi.string().valid('AA', 'BB', 'X'),
  rent: Joi.object().keys({
    price: Joi.number().required().precision(2),
    // max is allowed only when type is A or B
    // and subType is AA or BB.
    max: Joi.alternatives()
      .when('type', {
        is: Joi.valid('A', 'B'),
        then: Joi.alternatives().when('subType', {
            is: Joi.valid('AA', 'BB'),
            then: Joi.number(),
            otherwise: Joi.forbidden()
        }),
        otherwise: Joi.forbidden()
      })
  })
});
const obj = {
    type: 'A',
    subType: 'AA',
    rent: {
        price: 3000.25,
        max: 300.50,
    }
};
const result = Joi.validate(obj, schema);
console.log(result.error);
```

I expect validation to fail but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to validate the keys **type** and **subType** your validation must come after the object, for instance:

```
const schema = Joi.object({
        type: Joi.string().valid('A', 'B', 'C'),
        subType: Joi.string().valid('AA', 'BB', 'X'),
        rent: Joi.object({
            amount: Joi.number(),
            price: Joi.number().required().precision(2),
        })
    }).when(Joi.object({
        type: Joi.string().valid('A', 'B').required(),
        subType: Joi.string().valid('AA', 'BB').required()
    }).unknown(), {
        then: Joi.object({
            rent: Joi.object({
                amount: Joi.number().required()
            })
        }),
        otherwise: Joi.object({
            rent: Joi.object({
                amount: Joi.forbidden()
            })
        })
    });
```

This is the results for the following examples:

```
// FAIL - requires amount
   const obj = {
        type: 'A',
        subType: 'BB',
        rent: {
            price: 10
        }
    };

// FAIL - amount is not allowed
    const obj = {
        type: 'A',
        subType: 'X',
        rent: {
            amount: 3000.25,
            price: 300.50
        }
    };


// SUCCESS
    const obj = {
        type: 'A',
        subType: 'BB',
        rent: {
            amount: 3000.25,
            price: 300.50
        }
    };

// SUCCESS
   const obj = {
        type: 'A',
        subType: 'X',
        rent: {
            price: 300.50
        }

    };
```